# Can you deploy a smart contract from a webpage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, blockchain, solidity

I am trying to deploy a smart contract from a webpage. I am using react for frontend and I wrote a smart contract in solidity, but the contract is deployed only when I run the truffle commands in terminal. I want to deploy the contract when the user clicks a button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a deployment transaction from frontend using web3.js or ethers.js library. How to deploy a contract using these libraries, please [refer to the documentation of deploy function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy).